# Adiabatic Expansion with expanding control volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, adiabatic

I have a tube with a length $L$ and diameter $d$ that is open on 1 side.
At a certain point (say $x$) from the closed end of the tube, I have a gas with a high pressure.

At this point, $x$, there is also a weight of mass $m$.
It is also known what the velocity of the weight is at point $L$.

Initially:

[image: initial]

Finally:

[image: final]

Assuming that the tube is held stationary, what force is imparted on the closed section of tubing (left side)?

Basically, think of it as a rifle barrel with a bullet inside.  I wish to find a expression for the force on the closed end of the tube as it varies with time.

What I propose:
Determine the Work by the gas.  And since work is defined as $W = Fx $ and then $$ \frac{dW}{dt} = \frac{d(Fx)}{dt}.$$ Perhaps this could lead to an expression for force?

Comment: A drawing would help understanding the problem. Furthermore you might be better off using quantities like pressure, area and volume. Perhaps Boyle is applicable.

Comment: This is a moddeling of a non-ideal system.  Boyle's law as such wouldnt be accurate.  The adiabatic relations will be of more use along with the conservation of momentum and energy.  Also, no gas actually leaves the system, it just expands.